# Blank page error after product creation

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.9.0.1, simple-product

I'm manually creating some `configurable products` but whenever I save them and try to access my site, it shows a blank page. I found out the error occurs when I add the `simple products`. If those aren't added the site works just fine.

I've looked at the logs and there is only a `system.log` present which shows a notice for undifined indexes for images, but nothing else.

I've also added `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to `index.php` but it doesn't display any errors.

So my guess is that the simple products are wrongfully configured. I checked them and all seems fine, they are configured in the same way the other products are and those are working just fine.

My question is does anybody by change know what causes this error? Or at least some tips on how to further debug it?

Comment: Inside index.php there is already a line ini_set('display_errors', 1) but commented, so you don't need to add your one just uncommented that and below that write this line :- Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

Reload the page and check if you are able to see error now